# spark 3.2.2 job generating huge event log and job taking double time to execute compared to earlier version

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have a spark job written in spark 3.0.3, now we are migrating the job to spark 3.2.2 .
After migration we see below issue

Generated event log size is around 2GB earlier it was 500MB(in Spark 3.0.3)
Job took double time to run with the same resource. ( earlier it took 8 mins and now with 3.2.2 version took 16mins approx.)
See new stages are created in spark 3.2.2 version.
Is there any new parameter we have to configure for spark 3.2.2 version??

Another problem ,
Because of the huge eventlog size, we are unable to open history server UI for this particular job. getting

URI:    /history/spark-b4e49f2681f7407aa7182b241025e5b0/jobs/
STATUS:    500
MESSAGE:    org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
SERVLET:    org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$$anon$1-5bbbdd4b
CAUSED BY:    org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
CAUSED BY:    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Also we can see new stages are getting generated in spark 3.2.2 compared to spark 3.0.3 version.

Comment: Have you tried changing the log level on the context?

Comment: I'm also facing a log size issue, even with the log level set to ERROR, but I guess it is because my application does quite a lot of (complex) things. I don't really know how to fix this

Comment: log level change will not help here , as its spark internal event log

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue after migrating from 2.4.3 to 3.2 spark. If you find a solution I would be interested to hear!